# What is the purpose of logging/nologging option in Oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

What happens if I don't specify logging/nologging in database objects in Oracle? What I meant to say how would behave with logging/nologging  in database objects and without logging/nologging  in database objects?

Comment: Thanks to All, Just One Question to Jon Heller ; u have mentioned , bellow the chart "NOLOGGING option only helps for indexes during rebuilds." what do mean by that ? i did not understand,   i would really appreciate your support

Answer (score 24):

LOGGING/NOLOGGING helps manage enabling direct path writes in order to reduce the generation of REDO and UNDO.  It is one of several ways to control the delicate balance between recoverability and performance.

**Oracle Architecture Background Information**

*REDO* is how Oracle provides durability, the "D" in ACID.  When a transaction is committed the changes are not necessarily stored neatly in the datafiles.  That keeps things fast and lets background processes handle some work.  REDO is a description of the change.  It is stored quickly, on multiple disks, in a "dumb" log.  Changes are fast and if the server loses power one microsecond after the commit returned, Oracle can go through the REDO logs to make sure that change isn't lost.

*UNDO* helps Oracle provide consistency, the "C" in ACID.  It stores a description of how to reverse the change.  This information may be needed by another process that's reading the table and needs to know what the value *used* to be at an older point-in-time.

*Direct path writes* skip REDO, UNDO, the cache, and some other features, and directly modify data files.  This is a fast but potentially dangerous option in many environments, which is why there are so many confusing options to control it.  Direct path writes only apply to INSERTS, and only in the scenarios described below.

If you do nothing the default option is the safest, LOGGING.

**The Many Ways to Control Direct Path Writes**

LOGGING/NOLOGGING is one of several options to control direct path writes.  Look at this table from [AskTom](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:::NO:RP:P11_QUESTION_ID:5280714813869) to understand how the different options all work together:

```
Table Mode    Insert Mode     ArchiveLog mode      result
-----------   -------------   -----------------    ----------
LOGGING       APPEND          ARCHIVE LOG          redo generated
NOLOGGING     APPEND          ARCHIVE LOG          no redo
LOGGING       no append       ARCHIVE LOG          redo generated
NOLOGGING     no append       ARCHIVE LOG          redo generated
LOGGING       APPEND          noarchive log mode   no redo
NOLOGGING     APPEND          noarchive log mode   no redo
LOGGING       no append       noarchive log mode   redo generated
NOLOGGING     no append       noarchive log mode   redo generated
```

FORCE LOGGING can override all those settings.  There are probably some other switches I'm not aware of.  And of course there are the many limitations that prevent direct path - triggers, foreign keys, cluster, index organized tables, etc.

The rules are even more restrictive for indexes.  An index will *always* generate REDO during DML statements.  Only DDL statements, like `CREATE INDEX ... NOLOGGING` or `ALTER INDEX ... REBUILD` on a NOLOGGING index will not generate REDO.

Why are there so many ways?  Because recoverability is incredibly important and different roles may have different views on the matter.  And sometimes some people's decisions need to override others.

*Developers* decide at the statement level, "Insert Mode".  Many weird things can happen with an `/*+ APPEND */` hint and developers need to choose carefully when to use it.

*Architects* decide at the object level, "Table Mode".  Some tables, regardless of how fast a developer may want to insert into it, must always be recoverable.

*Database Administrators* decide at the database or tablespace mode, "Archive log" and FORCE LOGGING.  Maybe the organization just doesn't care about recovering a specific database, so set it to NOARCHIVELOG mode.  Or maybe the organization has a strict rule that everything must be recoverable, so set the tablespace to FORCE LOGGING.

Answer (score 1):

If you have table/index with nologging, then redo will not be generated when data is inserted into the object using direct path approaches such as insert /*+ append */.

However if database is in force logging mode then nologging will not have any affect. Redo is generated whether table/index is in logging or nologging mode.

Answer (score 1):

If `nologging` option is set redo logs won't be generated while inserting data. You can use this to increase significantly performance of for example INSERT statement when inserting large amount of data.

Be careful never to use `nologging` option under Data guard setup. DB replication relies on redologs so it'll a create pretty big mess you certainly want to avoid.