# Performance of date time concatenation into timestamp

Tags: oracle, performance, oracle12c, sql-tuning

Oracle 12C, non partitioned, no ASM.

This is the background. I have a table with multiple columns, 3 of them being -

```
TRAN_DATE                             DATE
TRAN_TIME                             TIMESTAMP(6)
FINAL_DATETIME                        NOT NULL TIMESTAMP(6)
```

The table has around 70 million records. What I want to do is concatenate the tran_date and the tran_time field and update the final_datetime field with that output, for all 70 million records.

This is the query I have -

```
update MYSCHEMA.MYTAB set FINAL_DATETIME = (to_timestamp( (to_char(tran_date, 'YYYY/MM/DD') || ' ' ||to_char(TRAN_TIME,'HH24MISS') ), 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF'))
```

Eg:

At present (for one record)

```
TRAN_DATE=01-DEC-16
TRAN_TIME=01-JAN-70 12.35.58.000000 AM    /*I need only the time part from this*/
FINAL_DATETIME=22-OCT-18 04.37.18.870000 PM
```

Post the query - the FINAL_DATETIME needs to be

```
01-DEC-16 12.35.58.000000 AM
```

The `to_timestamp` does require 2 character strings and I fear this will slow down the update a lot. Any suggestions?

What more can I do to increase performance? No one else will be using the table at this point, so, I do have the option to

- Drop indices
- Turn off logging

  and anything more anyone can suggest.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Instead of running a single update statement on 70 million records and committing only at the end, you may want to batch your updates and commit after each batch.

Comment: This is an option we are exploring, just worried that automating it might still require some level of oversight since it'll take time to complete.

Answer (score 1):

I would prefer CTAS method and your job would be simpler if you didn't have indexes, triggers and constraints on your table.

Create a new table for the column to be modified.

```
CREATE TABLE mytab_new
NOLOGGING
     AS
      SELECT /*+ FULL(mytab) PARALLEL(mytab, 10) */ --hint to speed up the select.
       CAST(tran_date AS TIMESTAMP) + ( tran_time - trunc(tran_time) ) AS final_datetime
          FROM mytab;
```

I have included only  one(**the final**) column in your new table because storing the other two in the new table is waste of resources. You may include other columns in `select` apart from the two now redundant ones.

Read [logging/nologging](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34081775/7998591) to know about `NOLOGGING` option in the select.

Next step is to rebuild indexes, triggers and constraints for the new table `new_mytab` using the definition from `mytab` for other columns if they exist.

Then rename the tables

```
rename mytab     to mytab_bkp;

rename mytab_new to mytab;
```

You may drop the table `mytab_bkp` after validating the new table or later when you feel you no longer need it.

[**Demo**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=f2d70ffe24196b450f59e0be80732a90)

Comment: I will try this, seems to be the option to go with, for now.