# How to turn off archive logging for table in oracle

Tags: database, oracle, logging

I have a table in Oracle db with a lot of inserts and updates. All these changes ends up in the archive log and makes the performance slow. How do I turn off archive logging for a table?

Comment: before I or anyone helps you do this, you should demonstrate you understand what it means to turn off this feature - also, google 'append hint' or 'nologging'.

Comment: Do you mean Oracle's built-in archive logging mode? Why do you think that's the source of your performance pain?

Comment: Disabling logging depends on the table mode, insert mode, and archivelog mode, as I describe in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34081775/409172). This situation is unfortunately a bit complicated because Oracle normally tries very hard to never lose data.